# Могу ли я изменить данные из памяти других приложений в Си?

Tags: c, память

В Си я могу делать вот так:

```
char a[2];
char *ptr = a;
*(ptr+200) = 5;
printf("%d\n", *(ptr+200));
```

Насколько это опасно и как далеко можно с этим зайти? Позволит мне ОС изменить что-то вне памяти самого приложения?
Если нет, то что за участок памяти меняет вышенаписанный код?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour, не более того :) Ни к чему хорошему это вас не приведет...

Comment: В современной ОС у вас нет никакого доступа "к памяти", а есть доступ только к воображаемому адресному пространству своего процесса. И наделить это адресное пространство свойствами "памяти", т.е. способностью что-то хранить, вы сможете только полностью контролируемыми запросами к ОС. Так что никуда вы тут "зайти" не сможете.

Comment: В C можно даже так, никакие дополнительные указатели не нужны: `*(char *)(0xB800) = 5;` :-) Но, как верно замечено, всё зависит от ОС. В DOS, например, именно так можно (и нужно) было работать с текстовой видеопамятью, реализовывать всякие "типа вирусные" технологии, манипуляции с таблицей векторов прерываний и т.д.

Comment: @AnT: Ну, можно воспользоваться системным API (`WriteProcessMemory` под Windows, например).

Comment: Для люниха - shmat, shmdt - System V shared memory operations. По личному  опыту могу сказать, что около 90% ошибок, вылезающих уже на этапе эксплуатации - ошибки при работе с указателями.

Comment: @AnT а к чему отностится и что подразумевается под понятием `undefined behavour` в случае с современными ОС если никуда 'зайти' не получится  ?